# Regex in java and ignoring white spaces

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex to match on a string and ignore white spaces.  For example, a search for 'foobar' would match on 'foo bar'.

Answer (score 4):

You can strip the spaces in both the pattern and search strings and use `indexOf()` if that's acceptable (might be a problem if you don't have enough memory to do so).

I don't think a regex would be a good idea, but you could basically make a pattern like:

```
/f\s*o\s*o\s*b\s*a\s*r/
```

Which basically has optional whitespaces in between every character.

Comment: Stripping spaces is the way to go. Don't even suggest the regex as an option just because the OP asked for it. :)

Comment: @casablanca I said "I don't think a regex would be a good idea," the OP can use it at their own peril ;)

Comment: stripping the white spaces is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe "I don't think a regex would be a good idea" should have been in bold... and blinking. :)

Comment: @Josh It isn't terrible either, because you won't have to create a new string in memory. Java's `String.replace()` uses regex anyways.

Comment: I would probably use a regex (or some other scanner code) if the string to match against was very large (so that I do not want to create a copy of it with whitespace removed).